# gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution while sending outlook email python

Tags: python

I am trying to send an outlook email in python.But I am getting this error.I tried using win 32 and many other ways but none of them work and I am unsure of the problem.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 


fromaddr = "anc@abc.com"
toaddr = "abc@abc.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "datalerty"

body = "sample"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "abc")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: It looks like you want `from email.mime.text import MIMEText`. It never hurts to [check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.mime.html)

Comment: You forgot to specify what version of Python you are using and what operating system you are using. And it's really helpful to show the exact stack trace when you have an unexpected exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Temporary failure in name resolution" usually means a problem with DNS. Check that the hostname you are using, `smtp-mail.outlook.com`, actually resolves. Can you ping it? Can you connect to it with `netcat` or another email program?

If the problem is intermittent, that's because networks are unreliable. Generally speaking, you need to expect these sort of problems and retry when they happen. Or let your application crash and assume something else will retry. But it's usually best done close to the error.

If the error happens consistently, you might have a misconfigured DNS server somewhere. Or maybe you are using an incorrect hostname, and the error is being badly reported by your operating system.

In any case, this *probably* isn't a problem with your Python code.