# How to trace DNS for intermittent python `socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, dns

I have an API that calls another API endpoint. An *extremely* simplified version of the Flask code can be considered

```
@app.route(route, methods=['POST'])
async def index():
    json = await request.get_json()
    headers = request.headers
    endpoint = "some endpoint that comes from other logic"
    # do some other work

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.post(endpoint, json=json, headers=headers)

    # do some other work
    return (output, 200)
```

Very very intermittently (approximately .07% of requests and only under heavy load) I see the following error that causes the code to crash out after about `10 seconds`

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

From this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238610/what-is-the-meaning-of-gaierror-errno-3-temporary-failure-in-name-resolutio) I've learned that this is a **G**et **a**ddress **i**nfo **error** (gaierror) that occurs from a problem with the DNS lookup stage. The endpoints I am calling exist though, as can be seen since the error is only intermittent across all endpoints and inputs without a real pattern.

This leads me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377263/gaierror-errno-3-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-while-sending-outlook) question which suggests that its probably a problem having to do with an unreliable network. My suspicion specifically is that in our internal network we might have a faulty DNS server, and want to see if I can trace this to check. As such I had some specific questions that I'd appreciate if anyone knew the answers to

1. Is it possible that this code is not `async` safe and a race condition could be causing a problem?
2. For this error and with the `aiohttp` library, is it possible to get a traceback / return of the IP of the DNS server that it attempted to hit so that I can verify to see if it is the same DNS server every time?